# PLINQ behaves differently in .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, plinq, c#-11.0, c#-12.0

Run the following code:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 31);

WriteLine("\nNumbers divisible by 5 are(using LINQ):");
numbers
.Where(num => num % 5 == 0)
.ToList()
.ForEach(num => Write($"{num}\t"));

WriteLine("\nNumbers divisible by 5 are(using PLINQ):");
numbers
.AsParallel()
.Where(num => num % 5 == 0)
.ToList()
.ForEach(num => Write($"{num}\t"));


WriteLine("\nNumbers divisible by 5 are(using PLINQ with forcing parallelism):");
numbers
.AsParallel()
.WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
.Where(num => num % 5 == 0)
.ToList()
.ForEach(num => Write($"{num}\t"));
```

Here is a sample output from .NET 7( Expected Behavior):

```
Numbers divisible by 5 are(using LINQ):
0       5       10      15      20      25      30
Numbers divisible by 5 are(using PLINQ):
5       20      25      0       30      15      10
Numbers divisible by 5 are(using PLINQ with forcing parallelism):
25      30      0       5       10      15      20
```

Now execute the same code in .NET 8:
**Everytime** I see the following output:

```
Numbers divisible by 5 are(using LINQ):
0       5       10      15      20      25      30
Numbers divisible by 5 are(using PLINQ):
0       5       10      15      20      25      30
Numbers divisible by 5 are(using PLINQ with forcing parallelism):
0       5       10      15      20      25      30
```

This is why it appears to me that the PLINQ engine is broken in .NET 8. Please correct me if I missed something here.

You can see that the PLINQ behavior in .NET 7 and .NET8 are different. In fact, .NET8 behavior is not a expected behavior.Any thought will be appretiated.

Comment: PLINQ doesn't behave differently. The "test" is wrong. 31 integers is so embarrassingly little data there's absolutely no reason to parallelize anything. The easily fits in the CPU's cache, if not in a *core's* AVX registers, in which case it makes no sense to pull it out just to send it to another core

Comment: "PLINQ doesn't behave differently. The "test" is wrong. 31 items is so embarrassingly little data there's absolutely no reason to parallelize anything. The data may already be in the CPU's cache" -Then how/ why .NET 7 is behaving differently?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _"31 integers is so embarrassingly little data there's absolutely no reason to parallelize anything."_ - depends on how long the processing of one integer takes =)

Comment: To add: as suggested, I have increased the data to 1000. The observation is same.

Comment: _"This is why it appears to me that the PLINQ engine is broken in .NET 8."_ - this is a quite strong statement for such test.

Comment: @ Guru Stron. Ok. But please do not deviate to a different direction. I have shared my observations to all of you. If any of you, see a different behavior ,I'll be happy to know.

Comment: Because .NET 8 is smarter and offers additional support for large AVX registers. A 512-bit AVX register can hold 32-bit integers. The entire operation is 2 MODs and 2 comparisons. Parallelizing this would be slower in any CPU though. And even 1000 is tiny data. The *cost* of RAM compared to cache access is far bigger than reading from the cache.

Comment: Finally, `ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism` is a *hint* that tells PLINQ what to chose when there's a tradeoff between serial or parallel execution. It doesn't force it to use a specific number of cores (that's the MaxDegreeOfParallelism option) or how to partition data before processing. I suspect actual BenchmarkDotNet timings will show .NET 8 is faster than .NET 7 with so little data

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: .NET 8 should be smarter and that is expected. But at the same time MSDN says( see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-execution-mode-in-plinq) : "....you can use the WithExecutionMode method and specify the ForceParallelism value to instruct PLINQ to always run the query as parallel."  Which means that the program does not follow the doc. Isn't it?

Comment: No, it means you misunderstand how PLINQ works *and* used the wrong hint. The number of cores is controlled by MaxDegreeOfParallelism. ForceParallelism is a hint when there's an option to choose between synchronous or parallel execution. And none of these affects the initial *partitioning*

Comment: Adding random delay "simulating" work "fixes" the "the issue" for me - `.Where(num => {Thread.Sleep(Random.Shared.Next(101, 200) - num); return num % 5 == 0;})`

Comment: The "problem" could be caused by the use of `Enumerable.Range()` - without knowing the number of items, PLINQ will try to use load balancing but the *same* core may always be free, so nothing needs to be sent to other cores. The result *may* be different if `Enumerable.Range().ToArray()` is used, in which case PLINQ will see a fixed-size array and decide to split it into batches

Comment: Or it could be JIT and dynamic optimization, which is on by default in .NET 8. The *first* time I execute the code I *don't* get ordered results. I do get ordered results in later executions. It's possible the JIT uses less efficient code the first time and replaces it with more efficient operations the *second* time. Stephen Toub's article on [.NET 8 performance improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-8/) explains how dynamic PGO is now on by default for all programs. It also describes new vectorization features and AVX512 support

Comment: Vaskaran Sarcar the `ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism` is not simply a hint (the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelexecutionmode) is pretty clear that it's not), and your understanding of PLINQ is quite decent. Don't allow yourself to be affected by the negativity.

Comment: I think what you are missing is that all the answers are correct - there is nothing about PLINQ that specifies what order the answers will be in, so their is nothing broken. You are assuming the order of the answers is an indicator of parallelism, which is a very poor assumption.

Comment: @NetMerge I am not sure whether all the answers are correct so far. It's true that a parallel execution does not guarantee an unordered output but at the same time, it is very unlikely that every time a parallel execution produces an ordered output ( even after you increase the dataset to 1000 integers). Anyone who writes a simple multithreaded program or as said before, runs the same code in .NET 7 can see it easily. Again- it is honest feedback and there is nothing to prove anyone right or wrong.